# Magento 2 Security Patches Tracking

Tags: magento2, security

I need to understand this new Magento 2 patches.

So I see that security patches are released as `2.3.3-p1`.

Let's say my version is `Magento 2.3.2`. And Magento has released `2.3.2-p1`, `2.3.3-p1`, `2.3.4-p1`, `2.3.5-p1` so far. Is that mean I need to apply only one patch ie. `2.3.2-p1` or all of these?

**Also,**

I see that for composer installation they have introduced a new way of getting the patch. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html#example---security-patch .

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-enterprise-edition=2.3.2-p1 <install-directory-name>
```

Just trying to understand how it will work on the already installed instance? Will it create a new project (create-project)?

I believe I need to apply the patch with this instead:

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.3.3-p1 --no-update
```

**Update**

So is this the process of applying patches after 2.3.3?

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.3-p1 --no-update
composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade //do I need to run this on security only patch/updates
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static:content:deploy
```

Especially do I need to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` on security only patches/updates?

Comment: do not get mislead with this, you must upgrade to the latest version, using patches only is wrong way.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Introducing-the-New-Security-only-Patch-Release/bc-p/445531

Comment: yes i know, but this is the caveat here, if your version is 2.3.3 - then you already need to upgrade to 2.3.5 and then 2.3.5-p1. security is good, but overall optimization introduced in 2.3.5 is much better. you need to keep your shop upgradable in time.